# How to Remember Checkbox Checked From Other Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances, jcheckbox

I have two jframe, one is a main frame used to call check box frame, and another one is a jframe containing checkbox.

MainFrame.java

[image]

How to remember previous checked checkbox after main frame call again the checkbox frame?

CheckBox.java

[image]

below is my button action code:

```
private void btn_callCheckBoxActionPerformed(
  java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //call checkbox window
    CheckBoxWindow cbw = new CheckBoxWindow();
    cbw.setVisible(true);
    cbw.setEnabled(true);

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setEnabled(false);

}
```

call mainframe from checkbox frame

```
private void btn_callMainFrameActionPerformed(
  java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //call main frame window
    MainPage mp = new MainPage();
    mp.setVisible(true);
    mp.setEnabled(true);
    this.setEnabled(false);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: surely there are better way rather than using database right?

Comment: In some class (or even the same class), save a `Map` or some relevant collection containing information about which buttons were clicked when the window with the checkboxes was navigated away from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have multiple options.

1- Do not create new windows every time you click the buttons. Save the windows in variables and use `setVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)` to show/hide them. If you hide the checkbox frame and the you show it again, the checkbox will be in the state before closing.

This something like this

```
 public MainPage() {
     this.checkWindow = new CheckWindow()
 }

 private void btn_callCheckBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {                                         
        // show window
        this.checkWindow.setVisible(true);
        this.checkWindow.setEnabled(true);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setEnabled(false);
  }
```

2.- Save and retrieve the values of the checkbox using the [preferences api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) of java

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you want:

In your CheckBoxWindow create a method that will return the boolean value of your selection

```
private boolean chck1=false;
private boolean chck2=false;

public boolean getCheckBoxOneState(){
    return chck1;
}
private void btn_callMainFrameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    chck1 = jCheckBox1.isSelected();
    chck2 = jCheckBox2.isSelected();
//call main frame window
MainPage mp = new MainPage();
mp.setVisible(true);
mp.setEnabled(true);
this.setEnabled(false);
this.setVisible(false);}
```

Then in your MainPage just instance the other frame an call the method that return the value of the checkbox

```
boolean chck1State = new CheckBoxWindow().getCheckBoxOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. cant solve it without you guys. i have succeed. i just have to hide the window and avoid creating new window when button is clicked.

```
\*
 *From Class MainFrame
 */
public MainFrame(){

this.CheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
}

//button action to show checkbox frame
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

CheckBox.setVisible(true);
}

\***********************************************************************\

\*
* From class CheckBox
\*

public CheckBox(JFrame mainFrame) {
this.MainFrame = MainFrame;
}

//button action to show MainFrame frame
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
MainFrame.setVisible();
}
```